# Remove \r from JSON response - Python

Tags: python, json, regex, python-3.x

Following code will query the table and result in a JSON as output

```
import boto3
import json
import re

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = dynamodb.Table('master')

    response = table.scan()
    data = response['Items']

    while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response:
        response = table.scan(ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey'])
        data.extend(response['Items'])

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
        },
        'body': json.dumps(data)
    }
```

My JSON response contains a \r.

```
[
    {
        "r_dt": "29-Oct-18",
        "de_dt": "31-Dec-99\r",
        "v_status": "R",
        "v_num": "M13020"
    },
    {
        "r_dt": "29-Oct-18",
        "de_dt": "31-Dec-99\r",
        "v_status": "R",
        "v_num": "O03873"
    }
}
```

How do I remove \r from from my JSON response? I tried JSON.loads/RegEx, but it didn't work

Comment: You have `\r` in your input data, so you have to fix your input data, not your JSON output.

Comment: unfortunately cant fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to remove \r from from my json reposnse. I tried json.loads/regex
>   , didnt work

Your input data contains `\r` so it ends up in JSON response. So, instead of "fixing" JSON output, you have to fix input data. If that's not possible, you have to sanitize data as early as possible, *before* serializing it to JSON:

```
def sanitize(item):
    item['de_dt'] = item['de_dt'].rstrip('\r')
    # OR
    item['de_dt'] = item['de_dt'].replace('\r', '')
    return item

# ...

while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response:
    response = table.scan(ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey'])
    data.extend(sanitize(item) for item in response['Items'])
```

Comment: list indices must be integers or slices, not str: TypeError - getting this error

Comment: Didn't notice that `response` is a list. Fix'd

Answer (score 0):

```
import boto3
import json
import re

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='ap-southeast-1')
    table = dynamodb.Table('dsl_vehicle_master')

    response = table.scan()
    data =[sanitize(item) for item in response['Items']]

    while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response:
        response = table.scan(ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey'])
        data.extend(sanitize(item) for item in response['Items'])


    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
        },
        'body': json.dumps(data)
    }

def sanitize(item):
    item['dereg_dt'] = item['dereg_dt'].rstrip('\r\n')
    # OR
    #item['dereg_dt'] = item['dereg_dt'].replace('\r', '')
    return item
```